# How to make an global variable available throughout php app to save on SQL requests

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, global-variables, hook

I have a set of data that I need to exlude from search in my website, this array variable needs to be fetched from a table [users] different from the search table [entries] only once a day. So I have set a daily cron job to get this list, then hook this list to the search function to exlude these entries.

I would like to know which is the best way to store this array variable [excluded users] and make it accessible and persistant throughout the webapp without having to do sql queries each time, scenarios I've already thought about:

**1:** adding a column to the search table to mark excluded entries (undesirable, cause this might be overriden by future updates of the app).

**2:** hooking a second function to the search function, that joins the second table [users] and adds the WHERE NOT IN statement (undesirable, cause I am trying to minimise redundant queries to the database that will yield the same result all day)

**3:** Store the excluded users list in a file, then read the file each time the search function gets called (not sure if this will reduce the excution time or be lighter on resources than making the same redundant sql query)

**4:** having a global variable that could be accessed from inside the search class and its methodes, something that lives in the RAM , and could be altered once a day (the ideal scenario but don't know of such variables in php)

Comment: Option 1 is the best option. Why would it be overwritten?

Comment: forgot to mention I am using an opensource CMS. so I might loose the modifications I make to the core code and database structure If I update it.

Comment: Can you make your own additional tables that aren't lost on updates?

Comment: The whole CMS is centered around entries and search. so I will have rewrite the big part of it to redirect all entries, search and comment to my own created table. That's too much work !

Comment: No, that's not what I had in mind. If you can do that, you could create a simple lookup table that would be updated once a day. Then you could do something similar to option 2, but instead of `WHERE NOT IN` you could simply join on a column in the lookup table, which would act as your "excluded" flag.

Comment: that's feaseable, so should I undersatand that according to you Joining another table's column at each search request is better than reading it from a file ? and to your knowledge php doesn't comprise something for the 4th scenario ?

Comment: I'd definitely say it's better than a file, because with a file you have to 1) query, 2) read file and 3) filter results, whereas with a join it's just a query. I don't know of anything that would support option 4, but maybe someone more knowledgeable could give you insight.

Comment: ok thanks for your input, I may procede that way!